# My AJAX function shuts down other JS and PHP stuff

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have several JS scripts that are loaded in my index page, including a JS script that includes

```
function ajaxrequest(php_file, purpose, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, where) {
    var request = getXMLHTTP(); // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance

    // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
    var the_data = 'purpose=' + purpose + '&var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2 + '&var3=' + var3 + '&var4=' + var4 + '&var5=' + var5 + '&var6=' + var6 + '&var7=' + var7 + '&var8=' + var8;

    request.open("POST", php_file, true); // set the request

    // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.send(the_data); // calls the send() method with datas as parameter

    // Check request status
    // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    };
}
```

Everything, including other JS functions found in the same file as the function above, works properly until THIS function is called. This function works everytime but any JS functions, PHP requires, and session_start() all seem to 'reset' and need to be reloaded. Is this normal and if not can you please assist in corrected this issue?

Comment: You say everything works properly until this is called, which sounds like there's an error in the code in this function. Are you sure there's no error? If there is no error, what exactly do you mean by things stop working? More information is needed to figure out what you're expecting and what's actually happening.

Comment: Theres a colorbox popup that comes after the ajaxrequest is fired. The colorbox popup seems to lose its JS scripting that is loaded on index.php. If I run the colorbox popup without running the ajaxrequest, it works as expected. That's why I suspect it has something to do with the ajaxrequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the functions that rely on page items after the AJAX page loads if you want that code to affect any new elements that were created after the AJAX finishes printing.

I'd wrap all the functions that I have in my JS to run when a mother function is called, kinda like this:

```
// In the beginning
function init(){
    // Functions that need to be fired when any page loads
    // etc etc
    // Code goes here...
}    

function ajaxrequest(php_file, purpose, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6, var7, var8, where) {
 // ...
    // Check request status
    // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById(where).innerHTML = request.responseText;
            init();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Will this solution solve this ajaxrequest from stopping any PHP requires and the session_start()? When the ajaxrequest runs, it does its request.open to ,for example, ajaxprocess.php. This first lines of code in ajaxprocess.php have to be session_start(); and do a PHP require for each file that ajaxprocess.php needs even tho these were all done on index.php. Hence my confusion.

Comment: When loading PHP files asynchronously, they load as seperate PHP files not dependent on the current page you're on. So if there are global variables that all your pages need, you'd need to include them on the actual .php file that you're trying to load with AJAX.

Comment: So having to restart the session_start and PHP require's is expected?

Comment: Yep - a PHP file is executed on call and all the functions that are required or included from other PHP files are executed immediately and only once. PHP is never executed from the client side, so once a page is loaded, the PHP for the page can't be changed short of an AJAX call and a reload.